# How to remove text from certain html tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension runs on social media websites. One of the things I want to be able to do is remove the number of subscribers a Youtuber has, but I have not been able to do this successfully.

From the code below I want to remove the "2.8M" and only that. I've only been able to delete the entire button.

```
<paper-button noink="" class="style-scope ytd-subscribe-button-renderer" role="button" aria-label="Subscribe to JRE Clips.">
<!--css-build:shady-->
  <yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytd-subscribe-button-renderer">Subscribe <span class="style-scope yt-formatted-string deemphasize">2.8M</span></yt-formatted-string>
</paper-button>
```

*Please use only JavaScript and no external libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.style-scope.yt-formatted-string.deemphasize')[0].innerText = '';
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you, I had tried variations of this but never with the array index. Thanks again.

Comment: Why use querySelectorAll()[0] when you could use querySelector() to select the first? And your selector could be better. No need to leave an empty node there.

Comment: @AndreSharghi you are right about better performance. Your solution is much better in this terms, I was just thinking that maybe there are multiple elements with the same classes on the page, so he can remove from all of them (but for simplicity I just used index zero).

Comment: Yes, please have a look at my suggestion for a complete answer

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
document.querySelector('paper-button yt-formatted-string span').remove();
```

If you are supporting IE, you should do:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('paper-button yt-formatted-string span');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

But you better check if it exits first, so it doesn't throw an error when YT updates their site:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('paper-button yt-formatted-string span');
if(elem)
   elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that can do that for you  :

```
function clearText(){
 document.querySelector('.yt-formatted-string ').innerHTML=''
}
```

And then call it where it's needed `clearText()`.